# What modification is required when paypal update there policy

Tags: magento, paypal

one of my client has receive a mail that paypal is upgrading there policy. When i do some r&d, i found similar thread on magento forum but no one has replied so far.Following are the link of that thread.
[PAYPAL SERVICE UPGRADES](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/871194/)

So my question, what modification i have to made in current configuration or there is huge changes required in current magento payment gatway coding.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major thrust of the quoted document is "don't use hard coded IP addresses".

Magento uses the server name, so DNS will resolve automatically to the new assigned netblocks.

Your Hosting Provider may have to modify their firewalls if they're filtering traffic, but it's probably unlikely. They also need to be running a web server that uses HTTP 1.1.

Viewing your web server's response headers will tell you that, look for `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

> Quoted PayPal notice of service upgrade
>
> If your site is:
>
> 1. Calling our APIs with a hardcoded PayPal API endpoint IP address, rather than using DNS resolution: Impact of upgrade: API calls will timeout or your will encounter an internal error from your system.
>
>    You need to: Use DNS resolution to access our API endpoints and/or open your firewall to the new IP addresses which will be communicated later.
> 2. Using HTTP methods other than GET, POST, DELETE and PUT: Impact of upgrade: API calls will return HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request or HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed.
>
>    You need to: Send the API requests using one of the allowed methods. Heartbeat calls using the HEAD method won’t be allowed.
> 3. Using the HTTP 1.0 protocol: Impact of upgrade: API calls will return HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.
>
>    You need to: Update your code to HTTP 1.1 and include the Host header in the API request.
> 4. Needing firewall changes to allow new IP addresses: Impact of upgrade: API calls will error out if your system responsible for making API calls to PayPal is behind a firewall that uses Access Control List (ACL) rules and limits outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses.
>
>    You need to: Update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to a new set of IP addresses we will be publishing. Test your integration on Sandbox (see the IP addresses for Sandbox API endpoints). The list of new IP addresses for our Live API endpoints will be posted here when available in January.